# perl defensive programming (die, assert, croak)

Tags: perl, assert, die, defensive-programming

What is the best (or recommended) approach to do defensive programming in perl?
For example if I have a sub which must be called with a (defined) SCALAR, an ARRAYREF and an optional HASHREF.

Three of the approaches I have seen:

```
sub test1 {
    die if !(@_ == 2 || @_ == 3);
    my ($scalar, $arrayref, $hashref) = @_;
    die if !defined($scalar) || ref($scalar);
    die if ref($arrayref) ne 'ARRAY';
    die if defined($hashref) && ref($hashref) ne 'HASH';
    #do s.th with scalar, arrayref and hashref
}

sub test2 {
    Carp::assert(@_ == 2 || @_ == 3) if DEBUG;
    my ($scalar, $arrayref, $hashref) = @_;
    if(DEBUG) {
        Carp::assert defined($scalar) && !ref($scalar);
        Carp::assert ref($arrayref) eq 'ARRAY';
        Carp::assert !defined($hashref) || ref($hashref) eq 'HASH';
    }
    #do s.th with scalar, arrayref and hashref
}

sub test3 {
    my ($scalar, $arrayref, $hashref) = @_;
    (@_ == 2 || @_ == 3 && defined($scalar) && !ref($scalar) && ref($arrayref) eq 'ARRAY' && (!defined($hashref) || ref($hashref) eq 'HASH'))
        or Carp::croak 'usage: test3(SCALAR, ARRAYREF, [HASHREF])';
    #do s.th with scalar, arrayref and hashref
}
```

Comment: There Is More Than One Way To Do It. All approaches have their pros and cons. Some approaches are more idiomatic/readable/concise/maintainable than others. I think the following is a more befitting title for this question: What is the most idiomatic way to check subroutine arguments?

Comment: Have you considered CPAN offerings? [`Params::Validate`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Params::Validate) and [`Type::Params`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Type::Params) look like good candidates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use Params::Validate qw(:all);

sub Yada {
   my (...)=validate_pos(@_,{ type=>SCALAR },{ type=>ARRAYREF },{ type=>HASHREF,optional=>1 });
   ...
}
```

Comment: FWIW, [here's how you'd do it with Type::Params](https://gist.github.com/tobyink/9177725) and [here's why you might want to use Type::Params instead of Params::Validate](https://metacpan.org/source/TOBYINK/Type-Tiny-0.038/examples/benchmark-param-validation.pl#L122).

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use any of them. Aside from not not accepting many array and hash references, the checks you used are almost always redundant.

```
>perl -we"use strict; sub { my ($x) = @_; my $y = $x->[0] }->( 'abc' )"
Can't use string ("abc") as an ARRAY ref nda"strict refs" in use at -e line 1.

>perl -we"use strict; sub { my ($x) = @_; my $y = $x->[0] }->( {} )"
Not an ARRAY reference at -e line 1.
```

The only advantage to checking is that you can use `croak` to show the caller in the error message.

---

Proper way to check if you have an reference to an array:

```
defined($x) && eval { @$x; 1 }
```

Proper way to check if you have an reference to a hash:

```
defined($x) && eval { %$x; 1 }
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the options you show display any message to give a *reason* for the failure, which I think is paramount.

It is also preferable to use `croak` instead of `die` from within library subroutines, so that the error is reported from the point of view of the caller.

I would replace all occurrences of `if !` with `unless`. The former is a C programmer's habit.

I suggest something like this

```
sub test1 {
    croak "Incorrect number of parameters" unless @_ == 2 or @_ == 3;
    my ($scalar, $arrayref, $hashref) = @_;
    croak "Invalid first parameter" unless $scalar and not ref $scalar;
    croak "Invalid second parameter" unless $arrayref eq 'ARRAY';
    croak "Invalid third parameter" if defined $hashref and ref $hashref ne 'HASH';

    # do s.th with scalar, arrayref and hashref
}
```